# Data not being sorted by date in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Here is my query:

```
WITH weekly_data AS (
  SELECT
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%-m-%-d', week_start) AS week_starting_from,
    CASE
      WHEN event_dow = 1 THEN 'Sunday'
      WHEN event_dow = 2 THEN 'Monday'
      WHEN event_dow = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
      WHEN event_dow = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
      WHEN event_dow = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
      WHEN event_dow = 6 THEN 'Friday'
      WHEN event_dow = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
      ELSE 'NA'
    END AS day_of_week,
    average_event_count,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY week_start ORDER BY average_event_count DESC) AS rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC(event_day, WEEK(MONDAY)) AS week_start,
      EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM event_day) AS event_dow,
      AVG(cnt) AS average_event_count
    FROM (
      SELECT
        TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), DAY) AS event_day,
        EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS event_dow,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM `table`
      WHERE
        event_name IN ("change_font")
        AND event_timestamp >= UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP '2022-05-22')
        AND event_timestamp < UNIX_MICROS(TIMESTAMP '2023-05-28')
      GROUP BY event_day, event_dow
    )
    GROUP BY week_start, event_dow
  )
)
SELECT
  week_starting_from,
  day_of_week,
  average_event_count
FROM weekly_data
#WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY week_starting_from DESC, average_event_count DESC#, day_of_week
```

The issue that the result set is not being sorted by "week_starting_from" even though it is explicity mentioned in the code. This is quite puzzling as I can't think why an order by clause would not work in this scenario.

Comment: You'd better use a format string `'%Y-%m-%d'` instead of `'%Y-%-m-%-d'` since you're comparing `week_starting_from` as `STRING` type.  With `'%Y-%-m-%-d'`, you'll compare '2023-6-9' and '2023-12-01' and you'll end up getting wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer as Wiki for better visibility for the communinty.

As @jaytiger recommended use this formating instead:

> '%Y-%m-%d'

As the initial formatting produce a different date format that will mismatch the comparison.

For extra reference and details you can visit this link for formatiing emelents: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements